ValueError that 'rope_scaling' must be a dictionary with two fields, 'type' and 'factor' Llama-3.1
When running Hermes-3-Llama-3.1-70B model, the job fails with the following output:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 12
      9 tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
     11 # Load the model with updated configurations
---> 12 pipe = transformers.LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
     13     model_name,
     14     torch_dtype=torch.float16,
     15     device_map="auto",
     16     quantization_config=transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True),
     17     use_flash_attention_2=True
     18 )

ValueError: `rope_scaling` must be a dictionary with two fields, `type` and `factor`, got {'factor': 8.0, 'high_freq_factor': 4.0, 'low_freq_factor': 1.0, 'original_max_position_embeddings': 8192, 'rope_type': 'llama3'}


I've tried changing the config.rope_scaling and applying it to the model but it doesn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This question is similar to: ValueError:'rope_scaling' must be a dictionary with two fields, 'type' and 'factor'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
